# replace param in cmd with msg

Tags: python, regex

How would I replace all {x} in the command data with their respective values from msg?
I have a regex for this in Perl that does the trick but will that work with Python?

```
data = "{1} {2}"
cmd = "!test"
msg = "!test param1 param2"

def parsecommand( data, cmd, msg, nick, channel ):
    print "Parsing command %s by %s on %s." % (cmd, nick, channel)
    msgparamcount = len(msg.split(' '))-1
    re1='.*?'
    re2='(\\{.*?\\})'
    re3='.*?'
    re4='(\\d)'
    rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    m = rg.search(data)
    if m:
        cbraces1=m.group(1)
        d1=m.group(2)
        print "("+cbraces1+")"+"("+d1+")"+"\n"
    return
```

Output

```
({1})(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the commands are as simple as you show them, then use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
data = "{1} {2}"
cmd = "!test"
msg = "!test param1 param2"
print(data.format(*msg.split()))
```

Just split the parameter string into a list and feed `format` with it.

If `cmd` might have an additional parameter then create a new message string. Strip the command from the message (`msg[len(cmd):`) and prepend it with a dummy command.

```
cmd = "!test xyz"
msg = '_ ' + msg[len(cmd):]
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the commands are dynamic.
They get loaded from a database.

Comment: Could you show some examples? It might work nevertheless.

Comment: Its not printing the result of the string format, any idea why? What kind of examples do you need?

Comment: I did not even realise that string.format used {x}! thanks.

Comment: So you've got your solution now? The fact that the data is coming from a database should change nothing concerning the logic.

Comment: Yup thanks so much. I am amazed at the fact that Python has a string.format that matches with {x}.

Comment: I don't know who invented this sysntax but given your task we can be thankful for it. :-)